# Change image fill color in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` with the source being an `ImageAsset`.

My image is a circle with a plus and I am looking to colour the inside of the circle only. How do I do that?

Using `setBackgroundColor` colours the whole of the view thus giving a square background like this:

[image].

Comment: I am not sure but You can use `VectorDrawable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a color tint to your `ImageView`. This will not affect your background if it's transparent, just the colored part (which is the circle and the plus)

```
imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR), 
                         android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

*Update*
Using `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN` will also work (if you don't need to multiply the source and destination pixels)

***Update 2***  
Since the destination part is not colored than the best solution is to use [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources).

You can use [VectorChildFinder](https://github.com/devsideal/VectorChildFinder) to find inner parts of your SVG resource and change its color.

```
VectorChildFinder vector = new VectorChildFinder(this, R.drawable.my_vector, imageView);

VectorDrawableCompat.VFullPath path1 = vector.findPathByName("path1");
path1.setFillColor(Color.RED);

imageView.invalidate();
```

to create your SVG, follow these steps :

1. Just click right button on folder(drawable for ex.) and choose:

[image]

2. then choose:

[image]

Comment: Problem is that all the non-white parts are transparent. Is there any way to colour just the "inside"?

Comment: I see.. check my updated answer.. using `VectorDrawable` will give you more options on how to manipulate your resrouce

Comment: I'll give it a try. How do I know the "name" of a specific "child"?

Comment: a child is a `<path>` in vector drawable. it has an attribute `android:name` that you use to find it

Comment: Thanks. Now it is just a matter of finding decent SVGs that differentiate between parts. So far the best I have found is one that has the circle, up line and down line separate. No entry for the inside or outside background.

Comment: There are many tools online that can transform png to svg this way you can later edit your svg as you wish (http://www.pngtosvg.com/)